# Trying to user mongodb's filter.near

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, lambda

I'm trying to find the nearest cordinations from a nested mongodb document. The error I keep getting is the following:

I've tried everything I could think of. I tried to add index 2d, that didn't work neither.

```
var point = GeoJson.Point(GeoJson.Geographic(38.8086, -85.1792));
var locationQuery = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Book>().NearSphere(tag => tag.CitiesInBook[-1].Location, point,
            5000); 
var query = collection.Find(locationQuery).Limit(10); 
var a =  query.ToList();
```

Planner returned error

> unable to find index for $geoNear query.'

Comment: What query did you run to create the 2d index?